# how do I update the x limits in a matplotlib figure in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I made a GUI with TKinter that reads a scope trace from a agilent scope. I want the x axis to update when I change time/div.  To update the x and y data I use `set_xdata` and `set_ydata`.  Is there a similar method for updating the x limits?

Comment: Do you want the range or the ticks to change?

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand a bit of the object  hierarchy.  You are calling `set_xdata`  on a `Line2D` object, which is an `Artist` which is associated with an `Axes` object (which handles things like log vs linear, the x/y limits, axis label, tick location and labels) which is associated with a `Figure` object (which groups together a bunch of axes objects, deals with the window manager (for gui), ect) and a `canvas` object (which actually deals with translating all of the other objects to a picture on the screen).

If you are using Tkinter, I assume that you have an `axes` object, (that I will call `ax`).

```
ax = fig.subplot(111) # or where ever you want to get you `Axes` object from.
my_line = ax.plot(data_x, data_y)
# whole bunch of code
#
# more other code


# update your line object
my_line.set_xdata(new_x_data)
my_line.set_ydata(new_y_data)

# update the limits of the axes object that you line is drawn on.
ax.set_xlim([top, bottom])
ax.set_ylim([left, right])
```

so to update the data in the line, you need to update `my_line`, to update the axes limits, you need to update `ax`.

`set_xlim` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim) and `set_ylim` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim)

Comment: my code is set up similar to this one I found on hear (answer 2).  I want to update the x limits in a similar way I update the y data.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997869/interactive-plot-based-on-tkinter-and-matplotlib

Comment: @MarkMitry thanks are nice, up votes and accepted answers are better ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [`pyplot.xlim()` function](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim) changes the range of the x axis (of the current Axes).

The [`set_xticks()` method](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks) of Axes sets the ticks. The current Axes can be obtained for instance with `gca()`.