# Unable to update Tkinter matplotlib graph with buttons and custom data

Tags: python, class, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm working on creating a program that utilizes `Tkinter` and `matplotlib`. I have 2 lists of lists (one for x-axis, one for y-axis) and I'm looking to have a button that can switch between the lists within the list. I took much of the code from the question [Interactive plot based on Tkinter and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997869/interactive-plot-based-on-tkinter-and-matplotlib), but I can't get the graph to update when the button is pressed. I'm quite new to using classes and having a bit of difficulty understanding them.

`tft` is the x-data `tf1` is the y-data in my code.

Example of data:

`x-data = [[1,2,3,4,5],[10,11,13,15,12,19],[20,25,27]]`

`y-data = [[5.4,6,10,11,6],[4,6,8,34,20,12],[45,25,50]]`

My code below will graph one of the lists within a list, but won't switch between the lists within that list when the button is pressed. The correct value for `event_num` also prints in the command window (the issue of `event_num` was solved in a previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222030/plotting-data-in-tkinter-with-matplotlib-switching-between-lists)).

There is no error that appears, the program only prints the number (when the button is pressed), but doesn't update the graph with the new data from the list.

## Preliminary Code (no issues--or there shouldn't be any)

```
#Importing Modules
import glob
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from Text_File_breakdown import Text_File_breakdown
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

#Initializing variables
important_imgs=[]
Image_dt=[]
building=[]
quick=[]
num=0
l=0
match=[]

#Getting the names of the image files
image_names=glob.glob("C:\Carbonite\EL_36604.02_231694\*.jpeg")


#image= Image.open(images_names[1])
#image.show()

#Text_File_breakdown(file,voltage limit,pts after lim, pts before lim)
tft,tf1,tf2=Text_File_breakdown('C:\Carbonite\EL_36604.02_231694.txt',3.0,5,5)
#tft= time of voltages      tf1=Voltage signal 1             tf2=Voltage signal 2
#Test Settings: 'C:\Carbonite\EL_36604.02_231694.txt',3.0,5,5


#Getting the Dates from the image names
for m in image_names:
    Idt=re.search("([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2})", m)
    Im_dat_tim=Idt.group(1)
    Im_dat_tim=datetime.strptime(Im_dat_tim, '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S')
    Image_dt.append(Im_dat_tim)
    Im_dat_tim=None

#Looking for the smallest difference between the voltage and image dates and associating an index number (index of the image_names variable) with each voltage time
for event in range(len(tft)):
    for i in range(len(tft[event])):
        diff=[tft[event][i]-Image_dt[0]]
        diff.append(tft[event][i]-Image_dt[0])
        while abs(diff[l])>=abs(diff[l+1]):
            l=l+1
            diff.append(tft[event][i]-Image_dt[l])
        match.append(l)
        l=0

#Arranging the index numbers (for the image_names variable) in a list of lists like tft variable
for count in range(len(tft)):
    for new in range(len(tft[count])):
        quick.append(match[num])
        num=num+1
    building.append(quick)
    quick=[]




plt.close('all')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(tft[1],tf1[1],'.')

# rotate and align the tick labels so they look better
fig.autofmt_xdate()

# use a more precise date string for the x axis locations in the
# toolbar
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
plt.title('Single Event')
```

## Continuation of code/Portion of code where the issue is:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.event_num = 1

        # Create a container
        frame = Frame(master)

        # Create 2 buttons
        self.button_left = Button(frame,text="< Previous Event",
                                    command=self.decrease)
        self.button_left.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.button_right = Button(frame,text="Next Event >",
                                    command=self.increase)
        self.button_right.grid(row=0,column=1)


        fig = Figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        fig.autofmt_xdate()
        import matplotlib.dates as mdates
        ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
        self.line, = ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')


        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=master)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1,column=0)
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def decrease(self):
        self.event_num -= 1
        print self.event_num
        self.line, = ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')
        self.canvas.draw()
        #self.canvas.draw(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')
        #self.line.set_xdata(tft[event_num])
        #self.line.set_ydata(tf1[event_num])



    def increase(self):
        self.event_num += 1        
        print self.event_num
        self.line, = ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')
        self.canvas.draw()
        #self.canvas.draw(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')
        #self.set_xdata(tft[event_num])
        #self.set_ydata(tf1[event_num])



root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Would you mind including your imports at the top of the code?

Comment: This question is a sequel to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222030/plotting-data-in-tkinter-with-matplotlib-switching-between-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are constantly plotting on a different set of axes than you think. `self.line, = ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')` refers to the axes that you created outside your class, not the axes in the figure you created in the `App` class. The problem can be remedied by creating `self.fig` and `self.ax` attributes:

```
class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.event_num = 1

        # Create a container
        frame = Frame(master)

        # Create 2 buttons
        self.button_left = Button(frame,text="< Previous Event",
                                    command=self.decrease)
        self.button_left.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.button_right = Button(frame,text="Next Event >",
                                    command=self.increase)
        self.button_right.grid(row=0,column=1)


        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.fig.autofmt_xdate()
        import matplotlib.dates as mdates
        self.ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')


        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,master=master)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1,column=0)
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def decrease(self):
        self.event_num -= 1
        print self.event_num
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')
        self.canvas.draw()

    def increase(self):
        self.event_num += 1        
        print self.event_num
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')
        self.canvas.draw()
```

Another (possible) problem is that the data gets appended to the plot instead of being replaced. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Turn `hold` off:  `self.ax.hold(False)` somewhere in `__init__()` before you plot anything.
2. Actually replace the plot data: Replace the line

   ```
   self.line, = self.ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')
   ```

   with

   ```
   self.line.set_xdata(tft[self.event_num])
   self.line.set_ydata(tf1[self.event_num])
   ```

Comment: I changed the variables to include the `self.` and used your option 2. I added an axis modifier from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514321/how-do-i-update-the-x-limits-in-a-matplotlib-figure-in-tkinter). It's working exactly as I imagined. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that helped. Any reason that you chose option 2 instead of 1?

Comment: Option 2 was something I was fairly familiar with and had played around with. I'm not sure what's going on in option 1.

Comment: Option 1 is the standard way to do this when coming from MATLAB. The `hold` property of an axes determines whether or not the axes reset with every call to `plot()`. When `hold` is `True`, calls to `plot()` append the line objects they create to the plot's current list. When `hold` is `False`, the new line objects overwrite the previous ones. I think that the color sequence and some other settings are reset as well. After thinking about it, I also prefer option 2 since it gives you much better control over what is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You are plotting to an axes in the global namespace but redrawing the canvas on another, unrelated global object. I think your issues are about global vs. local scope and the `self` object in object-oriented programming.

### **Python scoping**

Variables created in your file without indentation are in a file's **global** scope. `class` and `def` statements create **local** scopes. References to a variable name are resolved by checking scopes in this order:

- **Local** scope
- **Enclosing local** scope (enclosing `def`s only, not `class`es)
- **Global** scope
- **Builtins**

That cascade is only for *references*. *Assignments* to a variable name assign to the current global or local scope, period. A variable of that name will be created in the current scope if it doesn't already exist.

The bindings of local variables are deleted when a function returns. Values that are not bound are eventually garbage collected. If an assignment binds a global variable to a local variable's value, the value will persist with the global.

### **Applying this to your code**

There are two sets of figure/axes objects created in your code.

```
# From your top chunk of code
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# This line creates a global variable ax:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)                   
# From your bottom chunk of code
class App(self, master):
    def __init__(self, master):
        fig = Figure()
        # This line creates a local variable ax:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
        # This line references the local variable ax:
        ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
        # This line references the local variable ax, and binds its value 
        # to the attribute line of the self object, 
        # which is the global variable app:
        self.line, = ax.plot(x[self.event_n],y[self.event_n])

    def increase(self):
        self.event_num += 1        
        # This line references the global variable ax
        self.line, = ax.plot(x[self.event_n],y[self.event_n])
        # This line updates the object's canvas but the plot 
        # was made on the global axes:
        self.canvas.draw()
app = App(root)
```

You can fix this up by always referencing an Axes associated with your Tkinter root window:

- `self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)` to create enduring Axes.
- `self.ax.cla()` to remove the previous selection's data
- `self.ax.plot()` to add the data at the current `self.event_num` index
- `self.ax.set_xlim(x_min*0.9, x_max*0.9)` and `self.ax.set_ylim(y_min*1.1, y_max*1.1)` to keep the axes window consistent so as to visualize movement of the mean of data among inner lists. The `x_max`, `y_max`, `x_min`, and `y_min` can be determined before the main event loop by flattening the x and y lists and then using builtins `max()` and `min()`.